# Selemium and PhantomJS - Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium with GhostDriver and PhantomJS to take a screenshot of Webpages from a Java Webapp.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I suspect that the PhantomJSDriver is using the public ip of the server and maybe the firewall is not happy with that...

The project is working without any problem on my local machine (OSX) but not on the server (Debian 7).

```
2014-10-02 12:29:49,089 [ajp-8009-3] ERROR HibernateFilter - exception caught in hibernate filter for request
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03 10:52:47'
System info: host: 'debian', ip: '8.8.8.8', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-028stab093.2', java.version: '1.6.0_
31'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:110)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:89)
        at ...
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03 10:52:47'
System info: host: 'debina', ip: '8.8.8.8', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-028stab093.2', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:14083/status] to be available after 20007 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:258)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:119)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
        ... 40 more
```

**EDIT**

I found that host and ip from the `UnreachableBrowserException` are coming from `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` and `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`.

The timeout is actually coming from the localhost address `Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:12518/status] to be available after 20010 ms`.

Comment: Are you sure your server is correctly configured? I don't think that its IP address should be the same as Google DNS servers: `ip: '8.8.8.8'`.

Comment: Yes it's configure. I just changed the ip :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it had nothing to do with a timeout even though the message was close. In fact it was caused by the fact that ghost driver could not create its log file.

Check if you have this message before in your logs and if so, try to change permissions just to check.